# Need to optimize query to use in an indexed view

Tags: sql, indexing, view, sql-server-2008-r2

I have this query in a view that I cannot index because of the referenced table t. I've converted to a sub-query which doesn't work either and is a smidgen slower anyway.

I simply need the last price a productid was sold for.

```
SELECT op.productId, op.Price, o.createdat
from (
    SELECT max(op.OrderProductid), MAX(o.OrderId)
    FROM dbo.OrderProduct op
    INNER JOIN dbo.Order so ON op.OrderId = so.OrderId 
    WHERE o.StatusId IN (1,2,3)
    GROUP BY op.ProductId
) t
join OrderProduct op on op.Productid = t.Productid
join Order o ON o.OrderId = op.OrderId
```

Answer (score 1):

Considering your last statement:

> I simply need the last price a productid was sold for.

You can use `row_number` for this:

```
select *
from (
    select op.productid, op.price, o.createdat,
        row_number() over (partition by op.productid order by o.orderid desc) rn
    from orderproduct op 
        join order o on op.orderid = o.orderid
) t
where rn = 1
```

Comment: this takes 2x as long as my current query and can't be used to index a view